# Best way of generating a random number

Tags: apex, conversion, number, parsing

In order to get fake IDs for testing needs I wrote something that works and is reusable, but I'd like to know if there is better ways because my code seems heavy.

n is the total caracters of the string I want.

First, I think about the conversion between number and strings I could do better.

Got some ideas ?

```
final integer STRING_LENGTH = 14;
String aleaNumberN=String.valueOf((integer)(Math.ceil(Math.random()*9)));
for(integer j = 1; j<n; j++) {
    aleaNumberN += String.valueOf((integer)(Math.ceil(Math.random()*9)));
}
System.debug('aleaNumberN ? --> ' + aleaNumberN);
System.assert(aleaNumberN.length()==STRING_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Also, should I let the System.assert(condition) ? Or is it a best practise to have assertions only in test classes ? And is STRING_LENGTH well declared, as a final variable ?

Comment: Asserts should generally only be in test methods, or while testing code. Final variables are constants, and typically used for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

```
final integer STRING_LENGTH = 3;
final integer MIN = Math.pow(10,STRING_LENGTH -1); //Returns 100
final integer MAX = Math.pow(10,STRING_LENGTH) - 1; // Returns 999
String aleaNumberN = String.valueOf(Math.Round(Math.Random() * (MAX-MIN) + MIN));
```

If you replace some vars:

```
final integer STRING_LENGTH = 3;
String aleaNumberN = String.valueOf(Math.Round(Math.Random() * ((Math.pow(10,STRING_LENGTH) - 1)-Math.pow(10,STRING_LENGTH -1)) + Math.pow(10,STRING_LENGTH -1)));
```

Edit: Be carefull with string length, maybe using long is required

Update (Having 0's in the left):

```
final integer STRING_LENGTH = 3;
final integer MAX = Math.pow(10,STRING_LENGTH) - 1; // Returns 999
String aleaNumberN = String.valueOf(Math.Round(Math.Random() * MAX)).leftPad(STRING_LENGTH,'0');
```

Comment: Thanks ! The only thing I'd see, is that it's impossible to have a 0 in first character of the string. Also, you loose in lisibility when suppressing variables, is it better to have a more compact code, or to have one much more readable ? Is there a best practise about it ?

Comment: I would completly go for readability. For some reason I thought you were seeking the most compact way.
I have updated my answer with the possibility of having zeros in the left :)